# Help with understanding debgf log on a decision element in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, debug, debug-logs

I'm trying to understand what these lines mean when it says true and false on my debug log.

[image]

- **Line 1 says** False | False
- **Line 2 says** true | False
- **Line 3 says** true
- **Line 4 says** just false

What does the boolean value mean on the right?
What does the boolean value mean on the left?
What does the value mean if there is only boolean 1 value?

This is related to a decision element I have

[image]

[image]

Thank you